# Which Azure CLI commands to use to match the lists in Portal service Enterprise Apps

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I am trying to come up with Azure CLI commands that output the same lists as the Portal service
"Enterprise applications" or equivalently the menu command with the same name in Azure AD Dir/tenant

This service provides a list for each type: Enterprise Applications, Microsoft Applications, Managed Identities, All Applications. There is also 5th type included in the list for type "All Applications" but not in the other 3 types, e.g. service principals created with sth like

```
 az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MySPN"  // how to list them as separate list?
```

So far, I was able to come up with these but I cannot find anything for the rest.

```
 az ad sp list --all    // For "All Applications"
 az ad sp list --filter "servicePrincipalType eq 'ManagedIdentity'" --all   // For Managed Identities
```

For Microsoft Applications, I tried to reference the fixed Microsoft tenant id used by this type of apps

```
 az ad sp list --filter "appOwnerOrganizationId eq 'f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a'" --all
```

but I get the error

```
 Invalid filter clause
```

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have below applications with `Enterprise Applications` type in my Azure AD tenant like this:

[image]

To list these applications via **Azure CLI**, you can make use of below command:

```
az ad sp list --query "[?contains(tags, 'WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp')].displayName" --all --output tsv
```

**Response**

[image]

To confirm that, I ran below commands that gives **count** of above applications like this:

```
az ad sp list --query "[?contains(tags, 'WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp')].displayName |  length(@)" --all --output tsv
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, service principals created from `CLI/PowerShell` will be
> included in **All Applications** category by default and we cannot
> list them separately.

I have below applications of `Microsoft Applications` type in my Azure AD tenant like this:

[image]

Now, I ran below CLI command to fetch **Microsoft applications** along with service principals created from `CLI/PowerShell` by excluding *Enterprise applications* and *Managed Identities*  like this:

```
az ad sp list --query "[? !contains(tags, 'WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp') && servicePrincipalType != 'ManagedIdentity'].displayName" --all --output tsv
```

**Response:**

[image]

##### UPDATE:

When I tried to list service principals by filtering on the property "appOwnerOrganizationId" same as you via [***Graph Explorer***](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I got **same error** as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appOwnerOrganizationId eq 'f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a'
```

[image]

When I added **Advanced query parameters** in the query, I got response with list of `Microsoft applications` successfully like below:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appOwnerOrganizationId eq f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a&$count=true
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is strange for a tag alone to control the whole type of application. Another issue is why the CLI or PowerShell commands  cannot list by filtering  on the property "appOwnerOrganizationId"

Comment: Note that, filtering with [`appOwnerOrganizationId`](https://i.imgur.com/c0fGgW8.png) property requires Advanced query parameters as mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#legend). You can check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I tried it and it works now fine